# How do you create a Guava CacheBuilder in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, guava

What is the correct way to construct a Guava CacheBuilder in Kotlin?

I'm making a simple client side cache with CacheLoader and Guava based on an example. The example:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

The following translation of CacheLoader doesn't compile due to a package private constructor error:

```
       CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         fun load(key: Key): Graph {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key)
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a cache using CacheLoader.from { key: Key? -> value }. You need to type annotate the lambda argument and make it nullable.

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(1000)
        .build(
            CacheLoader.from { key: Key? -> createExpensiveGraph(key) }
        )
```